# Flutter ListWheelScrollView - position the list at top

Tags: flutter, listview, mobile

I'm using ListWheelScrollview to display a list of items. By default, the first item is shown at the center of the screen. Is there a way to move the list to the top of the screen? I do not see any property in the ListWheelScrollView class to change the position of the widget. I have tried setting Positioned and Align widgets as the list view's parent but that didn't help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks